# Insert new calendar in calendarList

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

It's not working I get no error. My new calendar doens't appear in my calendarlist even if everything seems to be created properly, any clue ?

```
public function insertCalendars($calendarSummary) {
    try {
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
        $calendar->setSummary($calendarSummary);
        $createdCalendar = $this->_service->calendars->insert($calendar);

        $calendarListEntry = new Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
        $calendarListEntry->setId($createdCalendar->getId());    
        $createdCalendarListEntry = $this->_service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
        return json_encode($createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary()); 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // wtv catching, there's no error anyway
    }

}
```

There is something I don't get. I get the calendars I added in my calendar list but it's not showing in the google calendar visualization. 
I'm using a service account and it seems this is the service account which own the calendars that's what I don't get.

So I shared some calendars from the admin account with the service account and it works. What I want is from the service account insert new calendars that I can see in the admin account, any idea how to do that and where are the calendars I created in the service account calendar list ? =D

Comment: you're swallowing the exception - are you sure it's not entering the catch block and then just disappearing. Might be useful to log or spit out any exceptions.

Comment: I've simplified the code but I guarantee no exception is catched